# When to release instance variables in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have a code snippet which goes like this:

```
-(void) getAccounts {
        accounts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        selAccounts=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://host/accts"];
        processor=[[AsynConnectionProcessorController alloc] init];
        processor.delegate=self;
        processor.server=self.server;
        [processor createRequestfromURL:url];
}
```

This view (account list) is called when I select view accounts and also when I come back to accounts list from account details view to which I go by selecting an account in the account list page. Each time I come back to the list accounts page from account detail page I see memory leakage in 'Instruments'. `accounts` and `selAccounts` are instance variables which I release in dealloc. My question is do I need to deallocate them anywhere else. May be in getAccounts function above if so how do I do it.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Don't call methods `get*` unless you are following Cocoa/iOS convention (which you aren't).  This should just be `accounts` or `retrieveAccounts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When to release instance variables in objective c?**

When you own resources, you need to release it. Now when do you own resources -

- You own it if you alloc it.
- You own it if you copy it.
- You own it if you new it. ( equivalent to alloc/init )

In your program, you need to **release** `accounts`, `selAccounts`, `processor`.

Comment: You also own it if you retain it. NARC: New/Alloc/Retain/Copy

Comment: But the problem is that this variable is an instance variable which I use elsewhere. I allocate it in getAccounts and I use asynchronous url processing with NSURLConnection, which returns the data which I store in the above variables. How else I should be doing this if I need to share variables among methods in a class?

Comment: The problem here is every time you call method `getAccounts`, you are reinitializing `accounts, selAccounts, processor` and leaving the memory where it was pointing earlier. This is causing memory leaks. If you need to keep track of all these locations pointed by these variables, maintain an array.

Comment: If you need to retain these ivars, you might want to alloc them in a farther out context, such as the init of the object which this method is from.

Comment: Thanks all, I don't want to keep earlier values. I can just discard them, the whole reason I am doing this each time is to discard earlier value. How can I discard earlier value?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you never called release for your object in your code.  Dealloc only gets called when you call release for your object

```
[yourObject release];
```